# How to get all blogs in Shopify store on any page?

Tags: html, shopify, e-commerce, liquid

I'm building a Shopify store and I want to create a list of recent blog posts and products, in chronological order of publication.
However I'm stumbling at the first hurdle as I am unable to access anything from the blogs. I have tried plugging both these solutions into my code and neither produces any output.

[One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57576300/shopify-theme-development-creating-news-page-where-news-is-a-blog-category?rq=1)

[Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68943064/shopify-all-blog-articles-on-one-blog-template)

I'm trying to show this list on the index/custom page, can the blogs global object only be accessed inside the blog template?
Any help/pointers appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can access the global variable in Shopify on any homepage, collection, or the product page.
Here is the list of [global variables](https://www.shopify.com/in/partners/shopify-cheat-sheet) into Shopify

More read about [articles](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects?shpxid=0b3b1c6d-11F1-470E-3773-F884AA18D8DD#articles) here.

and use like

```
{% assign article = articles['news'] %}
{{ article.title | link_to: article.url }}
```

or use blogs global object to get the articles using the handle.

```
{% for article in blogs.blog-handle.articles %}
  {{- article.title | link_to: article.url }}
{% endfor %}
```

here blog-handle is your handle slug want to fetch articles.

[image]